# How to compute the mean of a date range in R?

Tags: r

This is my tibble:

```
date;temp
1953-1-1;-0.2
1953-1-2;-0.2
1953-1-3;-0.2
1953-1-4;-0.1
...
1954-1-1;2
1954-1-2;3
1954-1-3;4
1954-1-4;5
...
1955-1-1;6
1955-1-2;7
1955-1-3;8
1955-1-4;9
```

I would now like to calculate the mean temperature per year. That means I want to calculate all values of the column `temp` for each year. However, I have no idea how I can work in R with the year numbers. Can someone tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: make a grouping variable (only year) => `regex`, use `data.table`, `dplyr` or `base::ave`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oCCxG7/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tb <- tb %>% 
mutate(year = substr(date, start=1, stop=4)) %>% 
group_by(year) %>% 
summarise(mean_temp = mean(temp, na.rm=TRUE))`

Otherwise, `lubridate` is a nice library to work with Dates.